# Watir with PhantomJS - I can set text on a textfield but the textfield is not registering the text

Tags: ruby, selenium, phantomjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I can successfully do a label_textfield.set "haha" or label_textfield.send_keys "haha" on this textfield using PhantomJS but for some reason, the text is not being noticed by the textfield.

e.g. in a normal browser (Google Chrome)

the text_field:
`<input class="**text not set**">`

the code:
text_field.when_present.set "haha"

the text_field:
`<input class="**text set**">`

e.g. in PhantomJS

the text_field: 
`<input class="**text not set**">`

the code:
text_field.when_present.set "haha"

the text_field:
`<input class="**text not set**">`

Has anyone else come across this? The text is definitely in the textfield but for some reason, the textfield isn't noticing the input.

Comment: You show the class attribute being different when set vs not set. Are you saying that there is some handler that is supposed to fire and change the input's class?

Comment: Yes there is. I think the front end is built using Angular or Node. It's very strange. It's the first time I've come across this to be honest. I tried to manipulate the class attribute of the textfield using browser.execute_script to disable the validations -- if the class attribute for the textfield is e.g. 'text not set' then clicking on the Submit button would throw a validation error message. Upon entering at least one character in the textfield, the class attribute of the textfield changes to e.g. 'text set' . I'm just using 'text not set' and 'text set' because the class name is too long

Comment: @JustinKo Just thought i'd tag you to get your attention lol It's my first time using Stack Overflow (signed up to get help with this problem) and I don't know if you'll get a notification if I added a comment below yours. Sorry for this redundant comment.

Comment: Do you know what event the text field is looking for? From a quick test, it looks like PhantomJS is at least responding to the keydown and keypress events.